# in R4.1.2 How to remove duplicate cells in a row leaving only the first cell

Tags: r

How to remove a repeated duplicate cell in row, leaving only the first cell.
(Remove the 2nd A3)

```
V1  V2  V3
A1  NA  C1
A2  NA  C2
A3  A3  C3
A4  NA  C4
A5  NA  C5
A6  NA  C6
A7  NA  C7
A8  NA  C8
```

my target

```
V1  V2  V3
A1  NA  C1
A2  NA  C2
A3  NA  C3
A4  NA  C4
A5  NA  C5
A6  NA  C6
A7  NA  C7
A8  NA  C8
```

Comment: `df$V2 <- ifelse(df$V1==df$V2, NA, V2)`

Comment: Tnank you all but my actual data is over 100 columns and I the repeated value may be in any column

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  V1 = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8"),
  V2 = c(NA, NA, "A3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  V3 = c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = if_else(V1 == V2, NA_character_, V2)) 

#>   V1   V2 V3
#> 1 A1 <NA> C1
#> 2 A2 <NA> C2
#> 3 A3 <NA> C3
#> 4 A4 <NA> C4
#> 5 A5 <NA> C5
#> 6 A6 <NA> C6
#> 7 A7 <NA> C7
#> 8 A8 <NA> C8
```

Comment: Rowwise is redundant here

Comment: Thanks, @AnilGoyal, for letting me know that! You are absolutely right!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(x in nrow(dataset)) 
{
if(dataset[x,2]%in%dataset[ ,1])
dataset[x, 2]<-NA
}
```

Something like this I guess

It should work even if the A3 is not in the same row as the A3 in the first column

If you need the target is to remove the same values only in the same row then replace if statement by

```
if(dataset[x,2]==dataset[x ,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace`.

```
transform(df, V2=replace(V2, V2 %in% V1, NA))
#   V1   V2 V3
# 1 A1 <NA> C1
# 2 A2 <NA> C2
# 3 A3 <NA> C3
# 4 A4 <NA> C4
# 5 A5 <NA> C5
# 6 A6 <NA> C6
# 7 A7 <NA> C7
# 8 A8 <NA> C8
```

Or `%in%` in `Reduce`.

```
df[Reduce(`%in%`, df[1:2]), 'V2'] <- NA
df
#   V1   V2 V3
# 1 A1 <NA> C1
# 2 A2 <NA> C2
# 3 A3 <NA> C3
# 4 A4 <NA> C4
# 5 A5 <NA> C5
# 6 A6 <NA> C6
# 7 A7 <NA> C7
# 8 A8 <NA> C8
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", 
"A8"), V2 = c(NA, NA, "A3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V3 = c("C1", 
"C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```